# Automotive relay contact rating, Can it handle 120vac?

Tags: relay

I have this [automotive relay](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062477), I would like to use it to switch a 120vac stereo that pulls around 9 amps. If the relay contact ratings are for 12vdc 30amps, how many amps can it handle at 120vac?

Will using this type of relay be safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably not safe for 120V AC. A relay will typically be able to handle a lower DC voltage than AC, but 12V versus 120V is a big difference.

Comment: Agreed. It's more to do with the clearance between the open contacts than the ampacity.

Comment: @Madmanguruman good point, I didn't think about the contact clearance. I'll shop for a proper relay.

Comment: Contact separation is function of the maximum voltage.

Comment: Would [this](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2049722&numProdsPerPage=60) be a relay suited for the job? As mentioned I need to switch on a 120vac stereo that pulls 9 amps according to the label on the back. It's supposed to be a 1000Wpeak amp.

Comment: @vilive - A relay's current must be derated depending on the kind of load. Yours will be inductive, and 9A in a 10A relay leaves you little headroom. Better look out for a 16A relay.